# How can I define a custom assign operator overload in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, operator-overloading, assignment-operator, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a Kotlin class that wraps a mutable value.

```kotlin
class StringWrapper(
  var value: String = ""
) {
  override fun toString(): String = value
}
```

I use this wrapper as properties in a custom data holder class

```kotlin
class DataHolder {
  val name = StringWrapper()

  override fun toString(): String = "Data(name=$name)"
}
```

I want to make it easier to assign values to the contents of `StringWrapper`

```kotlin
val dataAlpha = DataHolder()

// the '.value' is unnecessary noise
dataAlpha.name.value = "alpha"

// I want to directly assign a string value, but I get an error
dataAlpha.name = "alpha"  // ERROR Type mismatch. 
                          //   Required: StringWrapper 
                          //   Found: String
```

I also want to make it easier to copy one `StringWrapper` to another.

```
val dataAlpha = DataHolder()
dataAlpha.name = "alpha"

val dataAlphaCopy = DataHolder()

// I want to directly assign the value of `dataAlpha.name.value` into `dataAlphaCopy.name.value`
dataAlphaCopy.name = dataAlpha.name // ERROR Val cannot be reassigned
```

I understand that [Gradle 8.1 has a new experimental feature](https://docs.gradle.org/8.1/release-notes.html#kotlin-assign) in the Kotlin DSL that does what I want. How can I introduce the same assignment operators in my own library?

I have tried looking in the [operator overloading docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html), but there's no reference to an assignment operator.

There is a [KEEP language proposal for introducing such a feature](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/309), but [it was closed](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/309#issuecomment-1332347455).

I'm using Kotlin 1.8.20

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a new Kotlin (v1.8.0) compiler plugin that can be used to provide operator loading.

It hasn't been announced yet, but it's available for use. It's in the [Kotlin source code here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/v1.8.20/libraries/tools/kotlin-assignment). It's the same plugin that Gradle is using in the Kotlin DSL in [Gradle version 8.1](https://docs.gradle.org/8.1/release-notes.html#kotlin-assign).

Support in IntelliJ might be limited - make sure you're on the latest versions.

#### Applying the Kotlin Assignment compiler plugin

The Kotlin Assignment plugin can be applied like other Kotlin compiler plugins.

In Gradle projects it can be applied using [a simple Gradle plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.assignment).

I'm not familiar with compiling Kotlin using Maven, Ant, or via the CLI - but look at [the other Kotlin compiler plugin instructions for similar instructions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/all-open-plugin.html).

[ephemient has shared CLI instructions on Slack](https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/10078619/i-have-created-several-dsl-frameworks-in-kotlin-before-and-o#04824562-8ac5-498d-b6cd-f87e04607b22)

> ```
> $KOTLIN_HOME/bin/kotlinc-jvm -Xplugin=$KOTLIN_HOME/lib/assignment-compiler-plugin.jar -P plugin:org.jetbrains.kotlin.assignment:annotation=fqdn.SupportsKotlinAssignmentOverloading ...
> ```
>
> (you can see all the strings in https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/plugins/assign-plugin/assign-plugin.common/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/assignment/plugin/AssignmentPluginNames.kt)

#### Setting up assignment overloading

First create an annotation in your project

```
package my.project

/** Denotes types that will be processed by the Kotlin Assignment plugin */
@MustBeDocumented
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
annotation class KotlinAssignmentOverloadTarget
```

and then apply the plugin in Gradle, and configure it to use your annotation

```
plugins {
  kotlin("plugin.assignment") version "1.8.10"
}

assignment {
  annotation("my.project.KotlinAssignmentOverloadTarget")
}
```

Then in your code apply the annotation to `StringWrapper`.

```kotlin
@KotlinAssignmentOverloadTarget
class StringWrapper(
  var value: String = ""
) {
  override fun toString(): String = value
}
```

I recommend that the annotation should typically be applied to a 'wrapper' class that contains one (or possibly more) mutable values. It could also be applied to an interface which other similar classes implement ([which is what Gradle does](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/40ba32cde9d6daf2b92c39376d2758909dd6b813/subprojects/core-api/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/provider/Property.java#L49-L50)).

#### Writing assignment operators

Once the compiler plugin is applied and the annotation is set up, you can start writing overload operators.

- They *must* be named `assign` and return `Unit`.
- They *must* be [member functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#member-functions), or [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions).
- Note that they *don't* require the `operator` modifier typically used for [operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html).

```kotlin
@KotlinAssignmentOverloadTarget
class StringWrapper(
  var value: String = ""
) {

  // member function
  /** Provides overloaded setter for setting the value of [value] using an assignment syntax */
  fun assign(value: String) {
    this.value = value
  }
}

// extension function
/** Provides overloaded setter for setting the value of [value] using an assignment syntax */
fun StringWrapper.assign(value: StringWrapper) {
  this.value = value.value
}
```

#### Using assignment operators

You can now directly assign strings to the `name` property

```kotlin
val dataAlpha = DataHolder()
dataAlpha.name = "alpha"
println(dataAlpha) // prints: Data(name=alpha)
```

And also, using the extension function, assign one `StringWrapper` to another.

```kotlin
val dataAlphaCopy = DataHolder()
dataAlphaCopy.name = dataAlpha.name
println(dataAlphaCopy) // prints: Data(name=alpha)
```

### Limitations

#### Properties cannot be mutable

Operator overloading will not work when properties of type `StringWrapper` are `var`s. They must be `val`s.

```kotlin
class MutableDataHolder {
  var name = StringWrapper()
}

fun main() {
  val dataAlpha = MutableDataHolder()

  // no overload operator is generated, because name is a 'var'
  dataAlpha.name = "alpha" // ERROR Type mismatch.
}
```

#### Assignment overloading only works for member properties

Keep in mind that assignment overload *only* works when the properties are [member properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html).

So, when there's a `StringWrapper` value that is *not* a class property, the assignment overloader won't work.

```kotlin
val nameValue = StringWrapper()
nameValue = "123" // ERROR Val cannot be reassigned, and Type mismatch
```

Either manually call the `assign()` function, or create a class with a property. Using an [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#creating-anonymous-objects-from-scratch) also works.

```kotlin
val nameValue = StringWrapper()
// manually call the 'assign' function
nameValue.assign("123")

val values = object {
  val name = StringWrapper()
}
values.name = "123" // 'name' is a member property, so the assignment overload works
```